# Case Statement Assistance

Tags: sql, case, case-statement

I have a case statement currently built but need to add an extra layer and I'm not sure of the most efficient and accurate way of doing it. I have these drug codes that are for SYRINGE usage, and another set of codes for PEN usage. I have those layers built in, easy enough. I am trying to add a third layer to determine if the member used both a pen and a syringe, so the member would have a code from both categories during my specified time period. Any ideas? Thanks in advance for the help!

```
    , CASE WHEN NDC.GPI IN (
    '2710400300D220',
    '2710400300D233',
    '2710400300D236',
    '2710400400D220',
    '2799100225D220',
    '2799100235D220') THEN 'PEN'
    WHEN NDC.GPI IN ( 
    '27104004002022',
    '27104010002005',
    '27104020001805',
    '27104070001820',
    '2730001000E530') THEN 'SYRINGE'
    ELSE 'OTHER' END AS DOSAGE_FORM
```

Comment: You will need to use `EXISTS`, aggregation with `HAVING`, or outer-self-join.

Comment: Case expression is evaluated for each row so once a row has been assigned PEN then it will go to next row. Is there any other row identifier in the table that can identify someone is on "BOTH". Some sample data and expected output will help here to suggest solutions